# No certificate matches private key - OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

I spent all day trying to convert a .pem  file to a .p12, with no sucess.
Can you help me, please?

That's how i have been doing:
1) openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2048

2) openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -subj "/(...), CN=(...), C=(..)"

3) openssl x509 -in ios_development.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM

4) openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out ios_development.p12

Result: No certificate matches private key (in step 4)

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: how have you got `ios_development.cer` from file `CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest` ?

Comment: Yes, i have two ios_development.cer and none works.
In step 2, you must see written on cmd "loading screen into random state - done" and i don't see it. Could that be related?

Comment: In step 2 you have generated a CertificateSigningRequest (usually the suffix of the file is `.csr`, but you called it `.certSigningRequest`). This file must be sent to the Certification Authority. The CA generates and signs a certificate and returns you a `.cer`.  This step is not included in your question

Comment: Ok, first of all, thank you for the help.
So, is the code rigth? All that could be wrong is the .cer?

Comment: `No certificate matches private key` means private key of `.key` does not correspond with public key of `.cer`. So probably the `.cer` is not generated properly

Comment: So, just to be sure:
1) I generate a private key
2) I create the .csr
3) I upload .csr and download the .cer
4) I Convert .cer in .pem
5) Finally, i get the .p12 with the key submitted in step 2 (and uploaded to CA). Am i rigth?

Comment: Yes, those are the steps

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! :)